# AngularJS - using $resource with dynamic value returns TypeError: (intermediate value).$save is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am trying to call an API to get some data. In the controller, I do this:

```
new MyApi.Disconnect('test-item').$save().then(function(response) {...});
```

This is the service code:

```
var Disconnect = function (item) {
  return $resource('/api/v2/' + item + '/disconnect');
};
return {
    'Disconnect': Disconnect
}
```

`item` arrives fine here, but I get this error:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).$save is not a function

Please advise what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this can be done much simpler:

- send the item from the controller:

  ```
  new MyApi.DisconnectItem({item:'my-item'}).$save().then(function(response) { ...
  ```
- update the returned statement from the service:

  ```
  'DisconnectItem': $resource('/api/v2/:item/disconnect', {item: '@item'}),
  ```

Comment: Seems like a convoluted way to POST an empty object to a URL.